# Two problems with jquery script: z-index and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

have a side menu on the left side of the website. I want the submenu to slide open to the right with a neat animation. I have made the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".main-navigation ul li").mouseenter(function() {
        if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
            $(this).children("ul").css ({
            "display" : "block",
            }).animate({
                left: '250px',
                opacity: 1,
                }, 500)
            }})
            .mouseleave(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(this).children("ul").css({
                    "display" : "none",
                    "left" : "0px",
                    "opacity": 0,
                    }) 
                }, 1000);
            });
});
```

Sliding works just fine. The menu shows up nicely.

There's two problems though. One is, that the menu z-index doesn't work. The submenu's ul has a negative index set in css but when it slides it goes OVER the main ul. I want it to go UNDER the menu so it doesn't show. 
Second one is, the SetTimeout function doesn't seem to work. Once the mouse leaves the area the ul just stays there forever. Without the Settimeout function it disappears just nicely (instantly though, I want it to stay there awhile).

I have made a jsfiddle example 
http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/4/

Comment: It looks like your test environment uses an ancient version of jQuery. Your JSFiddle doesn't work because you are trying to use `live` with a recent version of the library. `live` was removed years ago.

Comment: What @Quentin said is correct, but to help out ... what you want to use now is `.on()` => http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have updated without the .live and just mouseenter

Comment: `this` inside the timeout is not the element, it's the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with z-index:

An element can not appear behind its parent. Since the submenu exists as a child element of the menu, it will not be able to appear behind the menu, z-index is really only applicable to two elements which share the same parent.

Problem with setTimeout:

The issue is most likely being caused because the `this` variable is out of scope by the time that the timeout occurs. This has an easy fix: create a global variable (say subMenu) and set `subMenu = this` before the timeout occurs and replace `this` with `subMenu` in your timeout function. You may use additional variables or a dictionary/array if you have multiple submenus to prevent the variable from being overwritten if two submenus get opened one right after the other

Comment: So, it's not possible? Could it be? (z-index)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible for a parent to appear in front of its child. I'm not 100% sure that there isn't a hack or workaround to make that happen, but I don't think there is. You can, however, use javascript to dynamically create or show an element and position it properly to have the effect you would like. This would be a different approach from your current one

Comment: But wouldn't that make the sub-menu items not the part of the menu? It's a wordpress website, so I'm reluctant to make such changes.

Comment: Hmm, I see your problem. I don't have any experience with wordpress so I'm not sure what you'd be able to do with it. You could use `removeChild` and `appendChild` to take the submenu off of the menu and append it to the parent of the menu, then re-append it when it goes away. Or you could change your animation so the sub-menus slide down instead of across :) that would be the easiest solution

Comment: Yeah, that could be one of the solutions. What I have in mind is creating a div that will do the sliding and only opacity the menu items. It'd be a bit different but I guess you gotta work around when it's not possible.

Comment: If you want to use the remove / append method, you can use this as a start: http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/6/ it removes the sub-menu and appends it to the menu so it can appear behind the other list elements. Don't have time to finish it now but maybe it can help you!

Answer (score 1):

It is because `$(this)` is losing its scope on `setTimeout` function. To overcome this issue, you can assign your `$(this)` scope into a variable like `$this` and then use it in your setTimeout function. Here is the code changes:

```
.mouseleave(function() {
        var $this=$(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.children("ul").css({
                "display" : "none",
                "left" : "0px",
                "opacity": 0,
            }) 
        }, 1000);
});
```

And here is your updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/5/

Comment: Yes, this solves the timeout problem. Thanks. Z-index is still an issue though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the setTimeout is the scope of `this`

When it runs, it is the window, not the menu.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".main-navigation ul li").mouseenter(function() {
        /* see if the timer has run yet, if it has not, cancel it */
        var hideTimer = $(this).data("timer");  
        if (hideTimer) window.clearTimeout(hideTimer);

        if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
            $(this).children("ul").css ({
            "display" : "block",
            }).stop().animate({
                left: '250px',
                opacity: 1,
                }, 500)
            }})
            .mouseleave(function() {
                /* store the children here to get rid of the "this" scope issue */
                var ul = $(this).children("ul"); 
                /* Store a reference to the timer so we can cancel it if they mouseover again */
                $(this).data("timer", setTimeout(function() {
                    ul.css({
                    "display" : "none",
                    "left" : "0px",
                    "opacity": 0,
                    }) 
                }, 1000));
            });
});
```

This will not fix the z-index issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is from the usage of "this" inside the callback of setTimeout sadly i do not have any computer to test out...
 See section "the this problem": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem
To solve it, save a reference of this before the call of setTimeout, and use the saved reference inside your callback